# XMLHttpRequest and Phonegap... Same Origin Policy or not?

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest, same-origin-policy

I'm still new to Phonegap and I am working with the Android SDK for some days now. At least I wanted to do a `XMLHttpRequest` to get data from my server. 
I knew about the Same Origin Policy before and I asked myself, how this should work with a "native app".

I searched the internet and found some topics, where people were telling others, that there is no Same Origin Policy on Phonegap, because it uses the `file://` protocol and additionally there is a domain whitelist in it's `config.xml`.

On the other hand there were a bunch of topics of people having problems with XHR's and others told them, that this is because of the Same Origin Policy...

Well, I was confused, but I used my - on regular websites - working `XMLHttpRequest` snippet and put it into the Phonegap app. I tried the virtual device, but my request is not working.

Now I asked myself some questions:

- Who is right? Is there Same Origin Policy on Phonegap or not?

If yes:

- What function has that domain whitelist?
- What's the best way to still get the data of my server?

Comment: Did you found a solution and a good answer for that. We think yes there is SOP on hybrid phonegapp apps. And yes there is now way to get it work. Or did you found a solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, people are correct the Same Origin Policy is needed only in webApps not hybrid phonegap apps.

You need to check you domain whitelist, just check it in the `config.xml` in `res` --> `xml` folder.

For accessing xml web services you need to ensure your soap message is correctly formed. try to catch the exact error.

Comment: At first thank you for your reply! My domain whitelist tells me <access origin="*" /> so there should be access to all websites? So I will have a look at my code... ;)

Comment: I finally found out, that my request didn't work because of my self signed certificate on my local webserver. Taking http instead of https let it work!

Comment: Hey @Sheetal I am confused with this.. I also can't call my Webservice.. :( need some good example, googling gonna confuse me..

Comment: self signed certificate at server will not help the app to make the web service call as it cannot manually provide the credentials required.  It has to be a properly signed certificate without manual intervention.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I wan't to make a XHR (http) requesto to https://blabla.com but I get a CORS problem because I have SOP issue. In my opinion domain whitelist doesn't matter with the CORS / SOP problem. right? can someone help?