# how to access a soap webservice with javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, cordova, jquery-mobile, soap

I'm having the following problem:

I'm developing a mobile app with HTML, JQuery Mobile and Cordova/PhoneGap and I have to make a request to a SOAP webservice but because of SOP (Same-origin Policy) I can't get to make it work.

So, how can I pass this problem? Are there any adjustments I need to make to my code or at the server side?

Will  be much appreciated for your help!

Below is my test code, I replaced my WS endpoint with (myURL) and my soapMessage with (XML) for security purposes.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
   <title>
      teste
   </title>
</head>

<body>
 <p id="nrtelefone"> </p>

<script>
var wsUrl = "(myURL)";
var soapMessage = '(XML)';

$.ajax({
 url: wsUrl,
 type: "POST",
 dataType : "xml",
 data: soapMessage,
processData: false,
contentType: "application/xml; charset=utf-8",
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $('#nrtelefone').text(data);
}, 
error: function(error){
    console.log(error);
    $('#nrtelefone').text(error.statusText);
}
});
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

PS: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782052/xmlhttprequest-and-phonegap-same-origin-policy-or-not) didn't helped.

Comment: You need to improve your question, show some code... I used ajax to request my SOAP WS without problems.

Comment: I'm using ajax too. I just added the code above.

Comment: `('channel':'Portal','countryCode':'PT-PT','data':'12-10-1992','indicativo':'351','nomeCliente':'351','source':'TS-DevTeam','time':'06:15:08','nTelefone':123456789')` doesn't look anything like XML to me.

Comment: `jQuery.support.cors = true;`  — Why are you overriding jQuery's CORS detection? If a browser doesn't support CORS then telling jQuery that it does it just going to create problems.

Comment: You're right, it isn't. I updated the code above with the right xml.
And deleted that line.
   
And I have read the question you left above and even with those alterations I keep getting:
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (ussd, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (ussd, line 0)
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load _WSDLEndpoint_. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. (index.html, line 0)

Comment: Since I can't answer, I'll leave it here: I fixed the problem. We had to make a alteration in our JBoss and Webservice project. You can read more about the alteration we made here: [link](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter.html)